# Unable to Deploy Android App Engine Project on Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I am create one smile application in Android + Google App Engine in eclipse. i am trying to deploy that app on Google app Engine but it show the error message

Log Cat :

Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=AppEngineTest2&version=1&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:282)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:235)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:214)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:160)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:127)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:323)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:400)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any one have simple Example(with Source code )  of Android + Google App Engine (c2dm) please share it ..

Comment: What is your application id ? AppEngineTest2 doesn't seems a valid one. Use the one created throught http://appengine.google.com/

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem as you and solved it in the following way:

1. Before uploading, first you have to create the application in the App Engine Administration Console (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading)
2. Check your application id. 
   The Application Identifier must be between 6 and 30 characters. Only Lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens (-) are acceptable characters. Leading and trailing hyphens are prohibited. - which means that **Uppercase letters are not allowed**.
3. appengine-web.xml needs the same application id with which you have created your application in the Administration console. Put this application id between the `<application>` tag.
4. Now you can deploy the application with Eclipse

Answer (score 5):

I found this recently as a bug of Eclipse or Google App Engine plugin.
Make sure that you specify the app id correctly in appengine-web.xml. It should be AppEngineTest2, not the URL (AppEngineTest2.appspot.com).