# I am currently unable to deploy my application by execute the following command: mvn appengine:update

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, deploying

I am currently unable to deploy my application by execute  the following command:  mvn appengine:update
I get the following error: 
Beginning interaction for module default...
25%initiating update 
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.abstract.ServerConnection send1
error posting url:https://app engine.google.com/api/version/create?app_id="idapp"&version="1.9.40"&400 bad request

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879197/unable-to-deploy-android-app-engine-project-on-google-app-engine